# Async callback difficulty and JavaScript object comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am learning JavaScript and Node.js, I'm currently making an Node.js app to manage my Philips hue lamps. And I am struggling with the asynchronous and callbacks.

First let me explain what I want to achieve. I have a function that gets the "id" of all my lights, `named getLightsId`:

```
function getLightsId(callback){
    args ={
        path:{"username":"username"}
    };

    client.registerMethod("getLightState", "bridge_adress/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

    client.methods.getLightState(args, function(data,response){
        var id = [];
        for(key in data){
            id.push(key);
        }
        callback(id);
    });
}
```

Then I have a function `getLightState` that gets the state of a specific lamp determined by its id:

```
function getLightState(id, callback){

    args ={
        path:{"username":"username", "id":id}
    };

    client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://bridge_address/api/${username}/lights/${id}", "GET");

    client.methods.getLightState(args, function(data,response){
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

And finally I have a function `initLightsState` that send the state of all the lights in an object to my client. Be prepared to see ugly code; it's pretty dirty, but hey, it works.

```
function initLightsState(callback){

    getLightsId(function(idArray) {

        var lightsState = new Object();

        idArray.forEach(function(id) {

            setInterval(function(){getLightState(id, function(state) {

                lightsState[id] = state;
            });},500);
        });

        callback(lightsState);
        io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
            setInterval(function(){
                socket.emit('updateLightsState', lightsState);
            },500);
        });
    });
}
```

I had to put a `setInterval()` to my `getLightState` function because otherwise it was always sending me the same object with the same data. Then I emit also with a `setInterval()` my object to my client.

The problem is that it's obviously spamming my client with the state of my lights. It works, but its very far from being the cleanest way to do this.

**What I want to do is to compare server-side the previous state of my light with the current one, and only if it's different send it to the client**.

But I'm stuck with the callback and everything and can't get it work. Could someone please show me the simplest way to do this?

I think i should use the async and deep-equal modules, but im really lost here..

Comment: Is this being done with a database? Or are you connecting to another web service? I'm unfamiliar with those lamps or what software runs them. Also, what are some of the other pieces to your framework here? Is just raw nodejs?

Comment: There is no database,  there is a 'bridge' that comes with the lamps, that bridge commands the lamps and provid a restful api. As you can see in my getLightsId function, i request that api in it. Also, this is just raw nodejs, no other framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution using async.waterfall from https://github.com/caolan/async

i am not sure if it the best way to do this, but it works quite well :
I finally found a solution, i am not sure if it is efficient, but it works, i used async.waterfall, thanks Floby for your help !

```
 // initialise previousState
 var previousState = "Original";

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
setInterval(function(){
        async.waterfall([
            function getLightsId(callback) {
                args = {
                    path: {
                        "username": "username"
                    }
                };

                client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://bridheip/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

                client.methods.getLightState(args, function (data, response) {
                    var ids = [];
                    for (key in data) {
                        ids.push(key);
                    }
                    callback(null, ids);
                });
            },
            function getLightsState(ids, callback) {
                var lightsState = new Object();
                async.reduce(ids, {}, function(lightsState, id, rcallback) {
                  getLightState(id, function(state) {
                    lightsState[id] = state;
                    rcallback(null, lightsState);
                    });
                }, callback);
            },
    ], 
    function (err, currentState) {
        if(JSON.stringify(currentState) !== JSON.stringify(previousState)){
            io.sockets.emit('updateLightsState', currentState);
            previousState = currentState;
            console.log("state changed");
        }            
    });
},1000);
 });
```